# What are the remedies for a trackpad suddenly malfunctioning?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, haptic-feedback

The trackpad on my 2017 MBP (no touch) has suddenly started functioning improperly, at times. It is ultra-sensitive at times, clicking everything every second while at other times it is inactive. No haptic bump, no clicking on screen. Is there a remedy for this? A way to reset it, so to speak?

Comment: have you checked your battery level?

Comment: @jmh yes...it has been plugged in. it is 100%